# Simple SQL Query to SUM values based on criteria in a different table

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 tables, claims and trans, like below:
[image: sql data]

I want to know how to write a query that will sum the `Pd` amount in `trans` based on the `Status` in `claims`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do some reading on [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) and [joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), you won't get very far with SQL without being intimately familiar with them.

```
SELECT trans.Claim, Status, SUM(Pd) FROM trans INNER JOIN claims ON trans.Claim = claims.Claim GROUP BY Status
```